# Can't get size of uploaded files containing non-english characters in Firefox on Windows

Tags: javascript, firefox, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I have an area on my webpage where users can drag and drop files and folders. Now I want to get the size of each file that are added by the user and list the current total size below the area.

When dropping a file or folder, I scan that item

```
dropzone.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
  let items = event.dataTransfer.items;

  event.preventDefault();

  for (let i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    let item = items[i];
    let entry = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();

    if (entry) {
        scanFiles(item, entry);
    }
  }
}, false);
```

This is by first checking if the item is a file or folder

```
function scanFiles(item, entry) {
  if (entry.isFile) {
    fileReadSuccess(item.getAsFile(), entry.fullPath);
  } else {
    readDirectory(entry.createReader());
  }
}
```

If it is a folder I traverse it to check for files and nested folders

```
function readDirectory(reader) {
  reader.readEntries(function (entries) {
    if (entries.length) {
      entries.forEach(function(entry) {
        if (entry.isFile) {
          var fullPath = entry.fullPath;
          entry.file(function (file) {
            fileReadSuccess(file, fullPath);
          }, readError);
        } else if (entry.isDirectory) {
          readDirectory(entry.createReader());
        }
      });
      readDirectory(reader);
    }
  }, readError);
}
```

Then I print each file and some of its properties to the console

```
function fileReadSuccess(file, fullPath) {
  console.log(file);
  console.log(fullPath);
  console.log(file.size);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5e6sLmjw/7)

Now this seems to work fine for all cases except one.

In Firefox 50.1.0 on Windows 10, dragging a folder containing files with names that have non-english characters (such as 'å', 'ä', 'ö') results in a `NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` error when calling `file.size`. However, dragging only the file works as expected.

I've tried the same thing in these browsers without any problems:

- Chrome 55.0.2883.95 - macOS 10.12.1
- Firefox 50.1.0 - macOS 10.12.1
- Firefox 50.1.0 - Ubuntu 16.04
- Microsoft Edge - Windows 10

---

Is this a bug in Firefox or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1323935) in Firefox and is currently fixed in Firefox Nightly and Developer Edition.

It will most likely be fixed in a public release as of Firefox 52.